# Facebook SDK: No Login.Callback in Android 4.4 but in >Android 5.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

somehow my Code dont work on Android 4.4 but on > Android 5.0

```
void setFacebookLoginPopUp() {
    LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();

    // Other app specific specialization
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
           ...
        }
    });
}
```

Normally the Facebook Login pops up and the user can login ...

[image: FacebookLogin]

Somehow that just wont work on Android 4.4 anymore (it used to work before i updated the library and did some refactoring)

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks and Regards,

Raymond

Answer (score 0):

You are adding this line right ?

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

What is not working ? the pop up window doesn´t pops up anymore ?